# How would you congratulate someone on a couple picture on Instagram?

Tags: traduction

A Belgian friend of mine uploaded a post dedicated to his girlfriend for the first time and I would like to congratulate him generally like in "nice picture" or "cute picture".

I thought of "très belle" or something like that, but I'm not sure if you would say that.

What would you say?

Comment: Bravo pour la photo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick's answer is great. Something like

"Sympa cette photo" could be good too.

But don't say : "Très belle" alone, because it can be understood as if you were talking about his girlfriend (if pictured) :)

Comment: I like all of your (the people responding) answers. It was tough choosing!

Answer (score 1):

"Belle photo" or "Jolie photo".

Answer (score 1):

> *Bravo pour la photo !* [Lambie, en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/47199/how-would-you-congratulate-someone-on-a-couple-picture-on-instagram#comment95874_47199)]